# Open-source OpenGL profiler for Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, performance

The title sums my question up pretty well: are there any *open source* OpenGL profilers for Linux?

The only thing I could find was [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerLinux.php), but it only comes with a 7 day trial and is very much closed source. I would use this for free (as in freedom) software development so paying is not an option, though I might consider accept answers for a free (as in beer) but closed application. Bonus points if it works with open source drivers (my main computer has an integrated Intel graphics card).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [BuGLe](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/). Its main target is not profiling, but it has a [filter](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/documentation/stats_calltimes.7.php), which shows the time spent in each OpenGL call.

Comment: +1! Not really what I need but this looks useful. And one can hope they include proper profiling support in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried out BuGLe and it is fantastic (as well as being free and open source). However, it took a bit of work to get some useful profiling output, so I added a [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859325/368821) describing in detail how I achieve good profiling output.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @cypheon's answer, I checked out BuGLe. It is fantastic, but I had to spend a bit of time getting useful profiling output. I wanted to add this as a comment on that answer, but I really need to paste full code examples so I started a new answer.

As he suggested, the [stats_calltimes](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/documentation/stats_calltimes.7.php) filter is good for profiling -- not ideal (since it doesn't show call stack information), but with a bit of work, it can show you the total flat time for each GL function per frame.

You need to edit both the `~/.bugle/filters` and `~/.bugle/statistics` files. Firstly, add this chain to the end of `filters`:

```
chain showcalltimes
{
    filterset stats_calls
    filterset stats_calltimes
    filterset showstats
    {
        show "average time per call"
    }
}
```

Now run your program with the command:

```
BUGLE_CHAIN=showcalltimes LD_PRELOAD=libbugle.so <your-program>
```

This will print the *average* time spent in each GL function per frame. That isn't terribly useful by itself, because for a call like `glVertex`, called thousands of times per frame, it will probably show up as 0.00ms even though the cumulative time is quite significant. So add a new entry to `statistics`:

```
"total time per call" = d("calls:*") / d("calls:*") * d("calltimes:*") / d("frames") * 1000
{
    precision 3
    label "* (ms)"
}
```

I used the same trick as the "calls per frame" statistic: multiply and divide by `d("calls:*")` to cause a divide-by-zero error for any function that was never called, to avoid showing 0.00 for all of the irrelevant functions.

Now, go back to the `showcalltimes` chain we added to `filters`, and change `"average time per call"` to `"total time per call"`:

```
chain showcalltimes
{
    filterset stats_calls
    filterset stats_calltimes
    filterset showstats
    {
        show "total time per call"
        #key_accumulate "A"
        #key_noaccumulate "I"
    }
}
```

And now we will see the useful stat of the total time spent in each function, per frame. If you want to average these stats out over many frames, uncomment the `key_accumulate` lines above, and then you can hit "A" (or remap it to a key of your choice) to start accumulating. Over time, you will see the statistics stop bouncing around so much as they average out over many frames.

You can also log these statistics to an output file with this chain:

```
chain logcalltimes
{
    filterset stats_calls
    filterset stats_calltimes
    filterset log
    {
        filename "bugle.log"
    }
    filterset logstats
    {
        show "total time per call"
    }
}
```

This is pretty hard to read, since it simply puts the individual stats for each frame one after the other, and I haven't found a way to average them over time. So my preferred method for reading statistics is the `showcalltimes` chain with the accumulator turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend this small profiler:http://silverspaceship.com/src/iprof/, it is not bound to profiling opengl, but does so very well! Also it can use opengl to display the profiling stats, which means it is very portable.

Comment: Aside from being interactive, how is this different than gprof, oprofile, callgrind, etc.? AFACIT it does not provide any means to do proper OpenGL profiling.

Comment: @staffan: I guess the only advantage it has is that it presents the profiling stats relative to the frametime. And you can have it running all the time, just freeze it if you experience a drop of framerate and step backwards until you see what profiling block caused the slowdown. I find it tricky to find framedrops when using static/logging profiling tools.

Answer (score 1):

> I would use this for free software development so paying is not an option

"Free" doesn't mean "opensource".

See if [NVPerfKit](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfkit_home.html), [NVPerfSDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfsdk_home.html) are suitable for you. i've used NVPerfHud for profiling DirectX applications before, and if NVPerfKit offers even a tiny bit of PerfHud's functionality for OpenGL, it will be exactly what you're looking for.

Also, check NVIdia's [OpenGL resources](http://developer.nvidia.com/page/opengl.html) page.

Comment: +1 since this is relevant and appears to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately I do not have a NVidia graphics card.

Comment: @Staffan: Well, you could see if this is what you want: http://developer.amd.com/gpu/StreamProfiler/Pages/default.aspx . Personally I prefer using NVidia cards for development (and haven't used ATI card in years), so I can't say if this "stream profiler" is suitable for your goals. Also, if you have card made by someone else(non-ATI, non-NVidia card), you *may* be out of luck.

Comment: @Staffan: Another (risky) option would be to use some kind of software OpenGL implementation and profile it using CPU profilers. The closest thing I can think of is Mesa3D, but it is not certified, and it is not totally compatible with OpenGL. To me it looks like performance data is vendor-dependent, so it is possible that there is no generic gpu profiler that is useful for every card.

Comment: Long-term I hope there will be a profiler targetting [Gallum3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium3d)-based drivers, since that will encompass all major vendors (Intel, ATI, NVidia through the nouveau driver). I know too little about Gallium3D to know if it's technically feasible but I hope it is! For the time being, I'm stuck with my stinky integrated Intel graphics...

Answer (score -1):

I also like vogl a lot - check it out at https://github.com/ValveSoftware/vogl

It has profiling, capturing, replay - but the killer features are the frame captures, you can inspect all buffers, shader vars and so on just by replaying your captured state.